# Long error while trying to install pyo library using pip on windows 10

Tags: python, pyo

I have a problem installing pyo, after a long fight with PATH problem when I try to install pyo library I have this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Michuxdd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Michuxdd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nbpbnzjj\\pyo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Michuxdd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nbpbnzjj\\pyo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Michuxdd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nbpbnzjj\pyo\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Michuxdd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nbpbnzjj\pyo\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Michuxdd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nbpbnzjj\pyo\setup.py", line 206, in <module>
        [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")]),
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] System can not find this path: 'win32dlls\\win32_pyo_data_files_common'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.</p>
```

I want to add that installing, other packages work perfectly

Comment: I see you are installing for 32-bit Python 3.8. If I look at the PyPI download page (https://pypi.org/project/pyo/#files) there appears to be a wheel for Python 3.8 64-bit but not for Python 3.8 32-bit. And the problem is with the DLL folder, which is where bitness really counts. If you still have a 3.7 environment, you could try installing `pyo` there to see if that makes the problem go away. That would more or less settle the matter.